# weird browser behavior

Tags: browser

can anyone explain me this weird browser behavior:

[gist link](https://gist.github.com/1827212)

It seems to be, that the browser gets the content of **$openingHours** to late. If I replace this var with a random text - everything is well structured. Has anyone an idea or some links, which would explain that?

Comment: what template engine are you using? are you sure you are processing the .html file with the engine and/or rendering the variable correctly?

Comment: that's of course a .tpl file - it's is an own ezPublish template engine, I think similiar to smarty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A paragraph cannot contain any other block-level elements (for example a table).

The HTML you are generating is not valid. It is possible that the browser is not able to interpret the table inside a paragraph and therefore makes its own conclusions.